# Best Practice for Circular Shapes - Industrial design

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Hope you are all well.

I am modelling a cookie cutter following an industrial design.
[image: Maria_biscuit_cutter_design]

I am using the curves to follow along the shape like so : [image: Curve]

It works fine.
Yet, I wonder if there wouldn't be a better way to do this, a more regular way where all instances of the design would be the same.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here, it appears that you're using vector handles everywhere.  You could use a radial array of a mesh object (array modifier from rotated empty), with merge enabled.  If it's important that this be evaluated as a curve object, non-destructively, you could use geometry nodes to mesh-to-curve it.

Comment: Since this is not a circle but an Ellipse, when using an array modifier as described above, you can apply the modifier and then scale it along one axis to get the elliptic shape.

Comment: if it is scaled on one axis in order to get an ellipse, the shape of each instance will be a bit deformed as well, is it a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, this question can also be answered with *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

This simply instantiates a given profile with a given number along a curve and distorts the positions of the points according to the curve.

Briefly explained:

First, the individual profile elements are instantiated one after the other along a straight line, which corresponds exactly to the length of the circle.

Then the individual points of the elements threaded one after the other are moved.

This is done by moving the points to a new position depending on the normals of the points of the base curve.

*Note:* The node `Subdivide Curve` divides the curve of the profile into smaller segments, which can result in a curvature of the profile. If this subdivision is not done, the result will be more edgy. You would have to adjust this subdivision according to your needs.

Have fun with it!

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: I'd say this is the best, most elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

A quick'n'dirty version of [@quellenform 's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258917/35559), knocking a GN group together to use as a modelling aid.

Why?

- In GN, a curve can quickly be adjusted, and resampled to 30 segments by length
- An object can be instanced along it, correctly rotated, but not deformed, without the old tricks to avoid deformation by the *Curve* modifier.
- This is not made for flexible re-use.. no trouble has been taken to tilt instances to the right orientation around the curve.. they've just been scaled to 0 in Z to flatten.

[image]

The input 'greek key' mesh is edited live to refernce. Scaling it up in Object Mode helps with precision. There are slight compromises .. in the reference, the keys are not perfectly identical. The resulting mesh can be converted to a curve in the group, and given a profile.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very good Complement to the first answer. I'd say both go hand in hand.
Thank you!

Comment: @GuillaumeAT For other folk's reference, the difference between them is that quellenform's deforms the elements, and this one doesn't. I've had a go at both. In this particular case, it makes no visible difference; the first answer is fine, and gets a +1 from me :)